# CM4 IO Board Fan I2C

Tags: i2c, compute-module-4

I'm using Raspberry PI OS image is 2021-03-04-raspios-buster-armhf-lite and I spotted in the product sheet for the Raspberry PI CM4IO (Compute Module 4 IO board) that it was i2c-10 assigned for the fan.

Certainly seems to be active..

```
sudo i2cdetect -l
i2c-10  i2c         i2c-11-mux (chan_id 1)              I2C adapter
i2c-1   i2c         bcm2835 (i2c@7e804000)              I2C adapter
i2c-11  i2c         bcm2835 (i2c@7e205000)              I2C adapter
i2c-0   i2c         i2c-11-mux (chan_id 0)              I2C adapter

 i2cdetect -y 10
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:                         -- -- -- -- 0c -- -- --
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 2f
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
50: -- 51 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
```

I have failed to find any more information via internet searches for this i2c resource... Though the RPI docs seem to point to it being a EMC2301 chipset.  https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/2301.pdf

Does anyone have any pointers or examples of using the i2c Fan controller on a CM4IO?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This reminds me of the fan built into the PoE hat. It uses the same I2C for control but there it's an AVR with some sort of custom firmware. I got similarly nothing when I tried to find out how that worked in hope of making a cooling fan hat that didn't need PWM. I wish you luck, and maybe this'll give you a lead?

Comment: Thanks.  I've discovered the i2C specification I'm just playing with some code to see if I can talk to the EMC2301 chip..

Comment: Well I’ve read some of the simpler values from the EMC2301 using a Python script.  Not yet figured out how to control the fan speed as of yet.

Comment: I this thread, there is an alternative but only for 64-bit OS. https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=308787 The code and instructions are in the GitHub repo : https://github.com/neg2led/cm4io-fan

Comment: Right... Have fun with this, it's written in C and based off of drivers and libs made by waveshare. if it cooks stuff, not my problem, but I'd like a video anyway as I think it'll be epic. https://github.com/Shuudoushi/EMC2301

Answer (score 1):

I'm in the same state, I'm seeing the `i2c` interface, and got the same response from the pi. I've tried to dive deeper, but I've found the i2c instance is not very accessible (for non-software engineers, like myself), as it is very low level.

Nevertheless, this is what I've found so far:

- If no I2C interface is available when running `sudo i2cdetect -y 10` (not recognized at all), the I2C interface might need to be enabled with `sudo raspi-config --> Interface Options --> I2C --> Enable` [reference](https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-i2c/).
- if you do not see the response of the `i2c` interface as above when you run `sudo i2cdetect -y 10` making some adjustments to your `/boot/config.txt` might help (add `dtparam=i2c_vc=on` and comment out `dtparam=audio=on`):  [reference](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=1783283)
- Similar thread on can be found [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=1759161), where it seems that there has been some progress on a Python package by `EcometTools` (see his comment in the previous link), see [GitHub repo](https://github.com/mamin27/ecomet_i2c_raspberry_tools/tree/master/i2c_pkg/emc2301_pkg)
- Support for the drivers in `lm_sensors` is not yet implemented, although there seems to be some kernel patch for the `EMC2301` out there already made by Reinhard Pfau: [linux discussion](http://lkml.iu.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/1306.1/02473.html).

This will be an important feature to enable integrating the CM4 into everyone's prototypes (got to keep things quiet and cool ;) ).
Hope this helps, and would really appreciate it when you share the solution if you got it working :).

Answer (score 1):

Have found a working solution to the control of the fan controller.
User neg2led has created a GitHub project for the kernel driver which includes install instructions here:-

https://github.com/neg2led/cm4io-fan

Please note that this is for 64bit kernels only.   I can confirm this works with Ubuntu 21.10 on the CM4IO board.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem so I made a simple Python wrapper around ecomet_i2c_raspberry_tools for Raspi CM4 IO Board.

Here's the repo: https://github.com/konsou/raspi-cm4-ioboard-fan

It's a work in progress but works on my Pi. Feel free to create issues to the repo if you want something fixed / made easier!

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/113647)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Having the same trouble. Pi4b, bought the Argon40 ssd case with programmable fan, etc. lost the docs but found this the other day.

Curl https://download.argon40.com//argon1.sh l bash
Hope this helps.